# all fields shuld be editable using inline edit method in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I need to write code in visual force for 'When in edit mode, all fields should be editable by default. Ie so you can tab between fields'.
I've used inline editing but it edits one field at a time and i cnt tab in between fields.
Does nybdy knw hw cn be this achieved??

Answer (score 0):

be sure to specify that your pageBlock component is in **edit mode**. then place all your input fields in that pageBlock:

> ```
> <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" mode="edit">
>   <apex:inputField value="{!obj.Field1__c}" />
>   <apex:inputField value="{!obj.Field2__c}" />
>   ...
>   <apex:inputField value="{!obj.FieldN__c}" />
> </apex:pageBlock>
> ```